# separate() or cSplit() first by "|" and then by ":" to populate data frame from a single column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  characteristicsAdditional                                                                                                                             
  <chr>                                                                                                                                                 
1 Tipo de inmueble:Piso|Estado:Bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Parking:Privado|Ascensor:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:                                     
2 Tipo de inmueble:Piso|Orientación:Sureste|Estado:Muy bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:                                         
3 Tipo de inmueble:Apartamento|Orientación:Este|Estado:Bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Parking:Comunitario|Ascensor:Sí|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisi…
4 Tipo de inmueble:Casa o chalet|Orientación:Sur|Agua caliente:Gas Natural|Calefacción:Propano|Estado:Casi nuevo|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisione…
5 Tipo de inmueble:Casa o chalet|Parking:Privado|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:                                                               
6 Tipo de inmueble:Casa adosada|Estado:Casi nuevo|Antigüedad:10 a 20 años|Parking:Privado|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:
```

It is in a single column `characteristicsAdditional` and I would like to split it in the following way:

1. First by `|` - since:

- `Tipo de inmueble:Piso` = type of building:apartment
- `Estado:Bien`  = state:good
- `Antigüedad:30 a 50 años` = age:30 to 50 years

etc. The characteristics are first grouped by `|`.
So, I am trying to split the single column into multiple columns using `|` - here I don't know the exact number of columns which will be constrcted.

I tried using `data %>%   splitstackshape::cSplit_e(., split.col = "characteristicsAdditional", sep = "|", type = "character")` but it does not get what I want since the `:` are causing it to create too many columns.

Using the above method gets me something like:

```
  characteristicsAdditional_Tipo de inmueble:Casa adosada characteristicsAdditional_Tipo de inmueble:Casa o chalet
1                                                      NA                                                       NA
2                                                      NA                                                       NA
3                                                      NA                                                       NA
4                                                      NA                                                        1
5                                                      NA                                                        1
6                                                       1                                                       NA
  characteristicsAdditional_Tipo de inmueble:Piso
1                                               1
2                                               1
3                                              NA
4                                              NA
5                                              NA
6                                              NA
```

Expected output:

```
tibble(
  `Tipo de inmueble` = c("piso", "piso", "Apartmento", "Casa o chalet", "Casa o chalet", "Casa adosada"),
  `Estado` = c("Bien", NA, NA, "Casi nuevo", NA, "Casi nuevo"),
  "Antigüedad" = c("30 a 50 años", "30 a 50 años", "30 a 50 años", NA, NA, "10 a 20 años"),
  `Parking` = c("Privado", NA, "Comunitario", NA, "Privado", "Privado"),
  "Consumo energía" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  "Emisiones" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  "Orientación" = c(NA, "Sureste", "Este", "Sur", NA, NA),
  "Agua" = c(NA, NA, NA, "Caliente", NA, NA)
)

# A tibble: 6 × 8
  `Tipo de inmueble` Estado     Antigüedad   Parking     `Consumo energía` Emisiones Orientación Agua    
  <chr>              <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       <lgl>             <lgl>     <chr>       <chr>   
1 piso               Bien       30 a 50 años Privado     NA                NA        NA          NA      
2 piso               NA         30 a 50 años NA          NA                NA        Sureste     NA      
3 Apartmento         NA         30 a 50 años Comunitario NA                NA        Este        NA      
4 Casa o chalet      Casi nuevo NA           NA          NA                NA        Sur         Caliente
5 Casa o chalet      NA         NA           Privado     NA                NA        NA          NA      
6 Casa adosada       Casi nuevo 10 a 20 años Privado     NA                NA        NA          NA
```

Data

```
data = structure(list(characteristicsAdditional = c("Tipo de inmueble:Piso|Estado:Bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Parking:Privado|Ascensor:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:", 
"Tipo de inmueble:Piso|Orientación:Sureste|Estado:Muy bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:", 
"Tipo de inmueble:Apartamento|Orientación:Este|Estado:Bien|Antigüedad:30 a 50 años|Parking:Comunitario|Ascensor:Sí|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:", 
"Tipo de inmueble:Casa o chalet|Orientación:Sur|Agua caliente:Gas Natural|Calefacción:Propano|Estado:Casi nuevo|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:", 
"Tipo de inmueble:Casa o chalet|Parking:Privado|Amueblado:Sí|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:", 
"Tipo de inmueble:Casa adosada|Estado:Casi nuevo|Antigüedad:10 a 20 años|Parking:Privado|Consumo energía:|Emisiones:"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may expand the rows of the first column `characteristicsAdditional` by splitting at the `|` with `separate_rows`, then split the column into two with `separate` and reshape back to wide with `pivot_wider` (create a row sequence initially)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(characteristicsAdditional, sep = "\\|") %>% 
   separate(characteristicsAdditional, into = c("key", "val"),
    sep = ":") %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = val) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  `Tipo de inmueble` Estado     Antigüedad   Parking     Ascensor `Consumo energía` Emisiones Orientación Amueblado `Agua caliente` Calefacción
  <chr>              <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       <chr>    <chr>             <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     <chr>           <chr>      
1 Piso               Bien       30 a 50 años Privado     Sí       ""                ""        <NA>        <NA>      <NA>            <NA>       
2 Piso               Muy bien   30 a 50 años <NA>        <NA>     ""                ""        Sureste     <NA>      <NA>            <NA>       
3 Apartamento        Bien       30 a 50 años Comunitario Sí       ""                ""        Este        Sí        <NA>            <NA>       
4 Casa o chalet      Casi nuevo <NA>         <NA>        <NA>     ""                ""        Sur         Sí        Gas Natural     Propano    
5 Casa o chalet      <NA>       <NA>         Privado     <NA>     ""                ""        <NA>        Sí        <NA>            <NA>       
6 Casa adosada       Casi nuevo 10 a 20 años Privado     <NA>     ""                ""        <NA>        <NA>      <NA>            <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted to achieve